# How does three phase add up?

Tags: three-phase

[image]

I understand that three phase allows you to always have a voltage, when another phase is in neutral, other phases will be at maximum peak.

What I don't understand is how three phase's add up? If all the phases are separated 120 degrees apart, however they all reach maximum peak in one cycle, and lets say each phase is 5VAC Would it be 15VAC per cycle since they're all reaching max peak in one cycle? Just overlapped 120 degrees apart.

Comment: Basically and fundamentally, they don't "add up".

Comment: What does it mean when equipment or even houses use either a variation of 115VAC or 230VAC, etc? How does three phase manipulate this? It seems to me they're adding up the separate peaks, just don't know how it's done.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here. What do you want to know?

Comment: 115VAC and 230VAC refer to the RMS voltage. In ordinary appliances this is single-phase, not three-phase. Exactly how this corresponds to the three-phase power depends on the wiring configuration of the various transformers in the distribution system--I don't know what the standard is.

Comment: You use a transformer? I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Andyaka: The power transfer is additive, although the voltage isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to think of three phase is as three "hot" wires and one neutral wire. Between any hot wire and neutral you will measure (say) 230 volts AC and usually a single household will receive one hot wire and neutral. Several houses further down the street a house might receive one of the other hot wires and neutral.

There are three circuits sharing a common wire called neutral and, as far as any single phase household is concerned they "see" a hot (live) and a neutral. Different names in different countries sometimes of course.

You could mistakingly supply two hot wires to a house and the voltage wouldn't be 230 V AC anymore - it would be about 400 volts because "line-to-line" voltage is \$\sqrt3\$ times bigger than line to neutral (often called "phase voltage"): -

[image]

So if Va is 230 volts and Vb is 230 volts, Vab is about 400 volts. It's just geometry.

Answer (score 1):

In Germany, the vast majority of households get three phases into the house and many have appliances that are quite power-hungry (like e.g. [tankless water heaters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tankless_water_heating), needing some 18kW for a nice hot shower) and therefore make good use of the triple power available.

But that aspect is not at the core of your question. Three-phase supply has some nice properties related to your question.

### Constant Power over Time

Three phases with 120 degrees phase shifts have the nice property that at every single moment during the whole cycle, you get the same overall power, i.e. the sum of the three powers provided over the three lines is constant over time. Remember that power goes with the square of the voltage.

Let's have a look at some example points in your graph.

- At the 90° point, Phase 1 voltage is at `+1.0`, while Phase 2 and Phase 3 are at `-0.5`. Take the squares and add them: `1.0 + 0.25 + 0.25 = 1.5`.
- At the 180° point, Phase 1 is `0.0`, Phase 2 is at `0.87`, and Phase 3 at `-0.87`. The power sum also is `0.0 + 0.75 + 0.75 = 1.5`

You can repeat this for every single point in the cycle, you always get a constant power equivalent to 1.5 times the peak power of a single phase, or three times the average power of a single phase.

### Zero Return Current

If you have well-balanced consumers on all three phases (same resistance between phase and neutral), then the neutral wire carries no current.

The neutral-wire return current is the sum of the three individual currents on the three phases, only in opposite direction.

Again, let's have a look at some example points in your graph. Now, we assume well-balanced consumers, so we can use the curves to indicate currents on the three phases.

- At the 90° point, Phase 1 current is at `+1.0`, while Phase 2 and Phase 3 are at `-0.5`. Add them: `1.0 - 0.5 - 0.5 = 0.0`.
- At the 180° point, Phase 1 is `0.0`, Phase 2 is at `0.87`, and Phase 3 at `-0.87`. The power sum also is `0.0 + 0.87 - 0.87 = 0.0`.

If you know that your three-pahse consumer is well-balanced, you can even omit the neutral wire, and you get the power of three single phases with half the wires:

- With single phases, you need three phase wires plus three return/neutral wires (or a single return wire capable of carrying three times the single currect).
- With three balanced phases, you only need the phase wires.

Comment: If you use three phases as separate phase-to-neutral supplies, you don't need the return wire to carry triple the current of a single phase. In fact, it only needs to carry the full current of one phase, because the worst case scenario, a maximally unbalanced load, would be one phase fully loaded and the other two at zero load. (or two phases fully loaded and the other one at zero load, which I think would work out to the same neutral current) (This is, of course, only true if your supply phases are 120° separated, as in normal three-phase operation.)